# DataGrid localization at runtime

Tags: wpf, datagrid, localization

I am using localization with MarkupExtension like in [Christians Mosers Wpf tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html).
So far everything works pretty good.

The only thing that does not work is the localization of DataGrid contents at runtime.
For example I have a datagrid that is bound to an observableCollection. It contains a TextColumn that displays a Feature name. The feature name should be localizable.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="{t:Translator Feature}" IsReadOnly="True"
  Binding="{Binding Path=Feature, Converter={Utilities:EnumDescriptionConverter}, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

The Feature is an enum value and I use a converter to retrieve the description from it. The converter also does the translation.

```
public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter,   System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
  if (value is Enum)
  {
    var myEnum = (Enum)value;
    string description = GetEnumDescription(myEnum);
    return TranslationManager.Instance.Translate(description);
  }

  return value;
}
```

The problem is that the converter is only called when the datagrid is filled for the first time. When the current culture changes the datagrid contents never change.

How could I get the datagrid contents to update every time the current language changes?

Comment: In  Christians Mosers Wpf tutorial's comments, someone mentions the fact that dynamic language switching does not work when using converters. Maybe you can trick a little : use multibinding to get the PropertyChanged from another property ?

Comment: You mean like a trigger?

Comment: I mean : suppose property A's binding does update ; property B doesn't. You can use a multibinding (A + B) just the make sure the binding to B will be updated (you kind of hook to the A PropertyChanged event). It's not really a trigger but when A will be updated it will trigger the update of B.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by having my ViewModel listen for LanguageChangedEvents. The eventhandler calls Refresh() on the underlying data views (of the datagrids) and also triggers the PropertyChangedEvents.

```
private void OnLanguageChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  //call refresh in order to update the translations within the list
  IEditableCollectionView list = (ListCollectionView) this.FeaturesView;
  if (list.IsEditingItem) list.CommitEdit();
  if (list.IsAddingNew) list.CommitNew();
  this.FeaturesView.Refresh();
  OnPropertyChanged(FeaturesViewProperty);

  ...
}
```